# Turn 4 columns into two

Tags: python, pandas

In Jupiter notebook, using pandas, I have a csv with 4 columns.

```
Names   Number   Names2   Number2
Jim     2        Greg     5
Meek    4        Drake    6
NaN     12       Tim      3
Neri    1        Nan      9
```

There are no duplicates between the two Name columns but there are `NaN`'s.

I am looking to

1. Create 2 new columns that appends the 4 columns
2. Remove the `NaN`'s in the process
3. Where there are `NaN` names remove the associated number aswell.

Desired Output

```
Names   Number   Names2   Number2  - NameList    NumberList
Jim     2        Greg     5          Jim         2
Meek    4        Drake    6          Meek        4
NaN     12       Tim      3          Neri        1
Neri    1        Nan      9          Greg        5
                                     Drake       6
                                     Tim         3
```

I have tried using `.append` but whenever I append, my new NameList column ends up just being the same length as one of the original columns or the `NaN`'s stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = df.replace('Nan', np.NaN)

df1 = pd.concat([pd.concat([df['Names'], df['Names2']]), pd.concat([df['Number'], df['Number2']])], axis=1).dropna().rename(columns={0: 'Nameslist', 1: 'Numberlist'}).reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
print(df1)

  Nameslist  Numberlist
0       Jim           2
1      Meek           4
2      Neri           1
3      Greg           5
4     Drake           6
5       Tim           3
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with a little modification on the first set of `Names` and `Number` column:

```
d = dict(zip(['Names','Number'],['Names1','Number1']))

(pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=d).reset_index()
                        ,['Names','Number'],'index','v')
                        .dropna(subset=['Names']).reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
   Names  Number
0    Jim       2
1   Meek       4
2   Neri       1
3   Greg       5
4  Drake       6
5    Tim       3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
(pd.concat([df,
            pd.DataFrame(
                {x.replace("2", ""): df.pop(x)
                 for x in ['Names2', 'Number2']})])) \
    .replace('Nan', np.NaN).dropna()
```

output,

```
   Names  Number
0    Jim       2
1   Meek       4
3   Neri       1
0   Greg       5
1  Drake       6
2    Tim       3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to concatenate while ignoring the column names and index, numpy can be a handy tool:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(
    [df[['Names', 'Number']].dropna().values,
    df[['Names2', 'Number2']].dropna().values]),
           columns=['NameList', 'NumberList'])
```

It gives:

```
  NameList NumberList
0      Jim          2
1     Meek          4
2     Neri          1
3     Greg          5
4    Drake          6
5      Tim          3
```

You can know concatenate on `axis=1`:

```
pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)
```

which gives as expected:

```
  Names  Number Names2  Number2 NameList NumberList
0   Jim     2.0   Greg      5.0      Jim          2
1  Meek     4.0  Drake      6.0     Meek          4
2   NaN    12.0    Tim      3.0     Neri          1
3  Neri     1.0    NaN      9.0     Greg          5
4   NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN    Drake          6
5   NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN      Tim          3
```